# Preventing float wrapping without setting parent width

Tags: css, css-float, whitespace

I would like to have several items stack horizontally infinitely (in one row), without setting the width of their parent container. I'm fully aware that setting the container div to width:1000px; will make them stack, but for various reasons I do not want to use this solution. Are there any alternatives?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div {white-space:nowrap; clear:none;}
div div {width:300px; border:1px solid black; float:left; display:inline;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div>x</div>
    <div>x</div>
    <div>x</div>
    <div>x</div>
    <div>x</div>
    <div>x</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need to `float` those `div`s in the example you gave to achieve stacking. If you really want to `float` then though, you can try applying `clear: left` to each `div`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
  float: none;
```

and on a parent element you'll need

```
  overflow:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessarily a robust solution, but if you can get exactly 300px of content in each of the inner divs, you could remove the float and width properties. Maybe include a 1x300 transparent image, and make sure you don't have too much text? Maybe

```
div.dummycontent {float:left; width:200px; background-color:Blue; }
<div class="dummycontent">&nbsp;</div>
```

Or if the reasons for not setting a width are primarily along the lines of not knowing until runtime what the size will need to be, maybe calculate with JavaScript, and set it then?